# How to get the location of a bezier curve's handle in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, bezier-curve

How can I get the exact coordinates of the handle point?

For reference its the coordinates of the blue points at the end of the handles I am interested in.

[image]

Comment: @AndrewH Awesome thanks! Figured someone had asked it before but couldn't find it for the life of me.

Comment: Also I've always found it slightly silly there is no way to give karma to people who identify duplicates since that increases the accessibility of the answer since additional terms can be used to search for it on SE or Google. Seems just as useful as proposing edits which if accepted grant +2 karma.

Comment: I was interested so I looked it up, seems this was a really popular question asked on stack exchange already [Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions/37478#37478). I think it would work well as a badge.

Comment: Here is another that might help http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50559/illustrator-how-to-draw-circles-at-control-points/50589#50589 it outlines how to do this for multiple handles in one go