# How can I change the size and rotation in an Illustrator script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

How do I change the size and rotation of the numbers in this script ?

```
var document = app.activeDocument;           //Use the current open Ai File
var selected = document.selection;           //Use the current selection in Ai

for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {  //Iterate over every selected object
    var text = document.textFrames.add();    //Add a new text object
    text.contents = i + 1;                   //Set the corresponding number text
    text.top = selected[i].top - 10;         //Position the text object underneath
    text.left = selected[i].left;
}
```

This script adds a number to every selection (group or path) from [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/57931/63979). I'm looking for a way to change the size and other appearances of the number.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you got the characterAttributes of a TextRange object, so you would do this for example, to change the font size:

`text.textRange.characterAttributes.size = 16; // make it 16pt font size`

Find more properties you can manipulate on page 17 of [this javascript reference pdf available online](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/illustrator/pdf/Illustrator_JavaScript_Scripting_Reference_2017.pdf)! Your newfound powers will only stoke your huger for more Adobe Illustrator scripting adventures. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

While you could change the script let me point a (obvious) trick that does not rely on you understanding how to change the script. Once youve done running the script:

1. Select all the newly created text objects (select → Object → all text objects)
2. Use **Window → Type → Character** to change the font
3. (opptional), use **Object → Transform → Transform Each...** to move them about.