# Numbering dots in illustrator - connect the dots

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke

I'd like to ask how can I automatically number dots in illustrator. I used the stroke key and dashed lines to make the dots, and I have no problem applying them to a path.

The problem I have is numbering them. I tried to follow these instructions and uploaded this script.

[How to add numbers to Adobe Illustrator anchor points?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57919/how-to-add-numbers-to-adobe-illustrator-anchor-points)

but it only numbers the first dot. When I try to run it again, it numbers the same dot, with a different number. I'd like for it to number all the dots i've created along that path.

How can i get it to work perfectly?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried expanding the path to individual shapes/objects? I think the script numbers objects, not anchors.

Comment: Hello. Take a look at Carlos Canto's answer. He tells how to separate each anchor in individual objects. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50559/illustrator-how-to-draw-circles-at-control-points/50589#50589

Comment: @BillyKerr I want to number the dots that are formed when you take a path, and create dots out of it with the stroke tool.

Comment: @LeoNas So if i use this tool, i will be able to turn those dots into objects, and afterwards apply that script to make them numbered?

Comment: I tested here and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm a gluten for punishment, but I'd do this simply with additional fills/strokes in the **Appearance Panel**... and the some transform Effects. This would tie the number to the circle.. and then I'd position them manually.

- Select the text with the **Selection Tool** (Black Arrow)
- Add a **new Fill** in the **Appearance Panel**
- Highlight that new fill and...
- Choose `Effect > Convert to Shape > Ellipse` from the menu and adjust (size)
- Then choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` from the menu and adjust the **Move** fields to position the circle where you want in relation to the number.

-- Repeat all the above for the stroke (or merely copy the effects from the fill tot he stroke)

[image]

[image]

Then all you need do is change the type (number). If the circle is positioned poorly, you can always readjust the fill and stroke to better accommodate the text.

[image]

Drag one of the text objects to the **Graphic Styles** panel and in the future, if you want the same configuration, you merely need to select a text object and click the Graphic Style in that panel.

[image]

Comment: your method worked, but it may not be ideal for large amounts of work. I took screenshots for you, can't find out how to upload an image. Been at it for a while now.

Comment: @tif333 You can’t add images to comments; edit the question and add them there as an update instead.

Comment: Your animation is very fast :-( +1.

Answer (score 0):

Bringing the comments to life the Carlos Cantos's tips + the use of the Script to number the objects(anchors in this case)...

Here are the steps to get what you want, I think.

The code I'm using here. Create a simple txt file. Place the code and save it as .jsx.

```
var document = app.activeDocument;           //Use the current open Ai File
var selected = document.selection;           //Use the current selection in Ai

for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {  //Iterate over every selected object
var text = document.textFrames.add();    //Add a new text object
text.contents = i + 1;                   //Set the corresponding number text
text.top = selected[i].top - 10;         //Position the text object underneath
text.left = selected[i].left;
}
```

Follow the image steps:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Leo, i tried your method, the script still didn't work. Scott, your method works, but i would have to apply the numbers across a large image, and i'd never finish my project. I took screenshots and i don't know how to upload them in the comments. I googled it and I can't find the image uploader so that i can link to them.

Comment: I just upload the script I used. Tested several times.